# Is it possible for one runway to have a different TORA in each direction?

Tags: runways

Is it possible that TORA is not the same for both directions on a single runway?

Comment: Do you mean one the same runway in opposite directions?

Comment: yes, same runway in opposite direction.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  If you look at the information for London Gatwick as an example, 08R has a TORA of 3159 meters, whereas 26L has a TORA of 3255 meters.

http://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/eadbasic/pamslight-7B4054FA19E6240FA6A62C9356F52804/7FE5QZZF3FXUS/EN/AIP/AD/EG_AD_2_EGKK_en_2018-12-06.pdf

Comment: How about runway length for both runways?

Comment: The strip of grass or tarmac will be the same length from whichever end you measure it.  However, there are a host of factors that affect the runway available for takeoff and landing.  You can see some other measures in the linked document headed TODA (take off distance available), ASDA (accelerate stop distance available) and LDA (landing distance available).  If you want more information on how any of those are calculated, you should ask a new question :)